# EF 6 - Performance of GroupBy

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I don't have a problem currently, but I want to make sure, that the performance is not too shabby for my issue. My search on Microsofts documentation was without any success.

I have a Entity of the name `Reservation`. I now want to add some statistics to the program, where I can see some metrics about the reservations (reservations per month and favorite spot/seat in particular).

Therefore, my first approach was the following:

```cs
public async Task<ICollection<StatisticElement<Seat>>> GetSeatUsage(Company company)
{
    var allReservations = await this.reservationService.GetAll(company);
    return await this.FetchGroupedSeatData(allReservations, company);
}

public async Task<ICollection<StatisticElement<DateTime>>> GetMonthlyReservations(Company company)
{
    var allReservations = await this.reservationService.GetAll(company);
    return this.FetchGroupedReservationData(allReservations);
}

private async Task<ICollection<StatisticElement<Seat>>> FetchGroupedSeatData(
    IEnumerable<Reservation> reservations,
    Company company)
{
    var groupedReservations = reservations.GroupBy(r => r.SeatId).ToList();
    var companySeats = await this.seatService.GetAll(company);

    return (from companySeat in companySeats
            let groupedReservation = groupedReservations.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == companySeat.Id)
            select new StatisticElement<Seat>()
                   {
                       Value = companySeat,
                       StatisticalCount = groupedReservation?.Count() ?? 0,
                   }).OrderByDescending(s => s.StatisticalCount).ToList();
}

private ICollection<StatisticElement<DateTime>> FetchGroupedReservationData(IEnumerable<Reservation> reservations)
{
    var groupedReservations = reservations.GroupBy(r => new { Month = r.Date.Month, Year = r.Date.Year }).ToList();

    return groupedReservations.Select(
                                      groupedReservation => new StatisticElement<DateTime>()
                                                            {
                                                                Value = new DateTime(groupedReservation.Key.Year, groupedReservation.Key.Month, 1),
                                                                StatisticalCount = groupedReservation.Count(),
                                                            }).
                               OrderBy(s => s.Value).
                               ToList();
}
```

To explain the code a little bit: With `GetSeatUsage` and `GetMonthlyReservations` I can get the above mentioned data of a company. Therefore, I fetch ALL reservations at first (with `reservationService.GetAll`) - this is the point, where I think the performance will be a problem in the future.

Afterwards, I call either `FetchGroupedSeatData` or `FetchGroupedReservationData`, which first groups the reservations I previously fetched from the database and then converts them in a, for me, usable format.

As I said, I think the group by after I have read ALL the data from the database MIGHT be a problem, but I cannot find any information regarding performance in the documentation.

My other idea was, that I create a new method in my `ReservationService`, which then already returns the grouped list. But, again, I can't find the information, that the EF adds the GroupBy to the DB Query or basically does it after all of the data has been read from the database. This method would look something like this:

```cs
return await this.Context.Set<Reservation>.Where(r => r.User.CompanyId == company.Id).GroupBy(r => r.SeatId).ToListAsync();
```

Is this already the solution? Where can I check that? Am I missing something completely obvious?